# Detect blocking overlay with selenium

Tags: css, selenium

I'm testing a website that opens in-browser pop-ups to display object details. These pop-ups are sometimes modal, by which I mean that they render the rest of the screen inoperative and trigger a gray transparent overlay that covers everything but the pop-up. This overlay is intended behavior, which means that I need a way to detect whether or not it was correctly triggered.

However, I am not familiar enough with the implementation of such overlays to determine where in the DOM I should look to find the properties that govern such behavior. As such, I was hoping someone with more information on how such overlays are usually configured could point me in the right direction.

The obvious solution is to simply try to click a button and see what happens but I was hoping to write a method that I could implement throughout the test suite rather than having to write a different check for each circumstance.

For those interested I'm scripting in Java using Selenium.

Comment: What if you press Escape to close the popup ?

Comment: I can get rid of the pop-up, that's not the problem. The overlay is desired behavior and I want to test whether or not it is appearing when it should.

Comment: Do you have a common class name for every popup that appears ? We can't help you much with the very few information you gave us ...

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but it may still help someone else. I had just recently solved a similar problem for our React site. I believe we were using the react-block-ui module to implement our blocking overlays.

Basically, I was able to detect a certain element was blocked by an overlay because of 2 known facts:

1. The element was within a containing div ("the overlay") that followed a certain naming convention. In our case, it was `section-overlay-X`.
2. This overlay would have a class attribute (named `av-block-ui`) if it was blocking.

(Hopefully, you have access to this information, too... or something similarly useful.)

With this information, I wrote up a couple utility methods to help me determine whether or not that particular `WebElement` is blocked by an overlay. If it was blocked, throw a `ElementNotInteractableException`.

For Java:

```
...
By SECTION_OVERLAY_ANCESTOR_LOCATOR = By.xpath("./ancestor::div[contains(@id, 'section-overlay-')][1]");
...

    private WebElement findUnblockedElement(By by) {
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(by);
    if (isBlockedByOverlay(element)) {
        throw new ElementNotInteractableException(String.format("Element [%s] is blocked by overlay", element.getAttribute("id")));
    } else {
        return element;
    }
    }

    private boolean isBlockedByOverlay(WebElement element) {
    List<WebElement> ancestors = element.findElements(SECTION_OVERLAY_ANCESTOR_LOCATOR);
    WebElement overlayAncestor = ancestors.get(0);
    String overlayClass = overlayAncestor.getAttribute("class");
    return !StringUtils.isBlank(overlayClass);
    }
```

Here's my snippet on it:
https://bitbucket.org/snippets/v_dev/BAd9dq/findunblockedelement

Answer (score 0):

This won't work in all situations, but I solved this problem by checking the overflow value of the body element.  The flavor of modal I was trying to get past disabled scrolling of the page while it was active.

Answer (score 0):

This is very old question but appeared first when Googling for the same issue.

I have resolved this using Javascript and executing the following function whenever checking for visible elements:

```js
function isObstructed(element) {
    const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    // X and Y are the center of the element
    const x = rect.left + rect.width / 2;
    const y = rect.top + rect.height / 2;
    const topElement = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
    return !element.isSameNode(topElement);
}
```

Combining this with Selenium's default visibility I managed to only interact with elements that are not under an overlay.